# Do the Penalties from the Power Attack and Stunning Assault Feats stack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, stacking

The Power Attack feat allows you to choose to take a –1 penalty on all melee attack rolls and combat maneuver checks to gain a +2 bonus on all melee damage rolls.

The Stunning Assault feat, which lists Power Attack as a prerequisite, allows you to choose to take a –5 penalty on all melee attack rolls and combat maneuver checks to stun targets you hit with your melee attacks for 1 round.

Does this mean that using the two feats together requires you to take a cumulative –10 penalty to your melee attack rolls?

Answer (score 3):

#### Yes, the penalties stack

Since they are untyped, they stack if you are taking them both together:

> Bonus Types: Usually, a bonus has a type that indicates how the spell grants the bonus. The important aspect of bonus types is that two bonuses of the same type don't generally stack. With the exception of dodge bonuses, most circumstance bonuses, and racial bonuses, only the better bonus of a given type works (see Combining Magical Effects). The same principle applies to penalties—a character taking two or more penalties of the same type applies only the worst one, **although most penalties have no type and thus always stack. Bonuses without a type always stack, unless they are from the same source.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, John. It’s what I was afraid of.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, you take both penalties

When making attacks with both Power Attack (at the required 16+BAB for Stunning Assault) and Stunning Assault active, which is completely valid, you take -5 (untyped) penalty from each resulting in -10 total. This is based on the rules on [stacking](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/BASICS-ABILITY-SCORES/GLOSSARY/#Stacking) and [penalties](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/BASICS-ABILITY-SCORES/GLOSSARY/#Penalty),

> Penalties are numerical values that are subtracted from a check or statistical score. Penalties do not have a type and most penalties stack with one another.

Comment: I suspected that might be the case, Ifusaso. I appreciate you verifying this!